# I'm having issues converting python .pack() to .grid()

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having issues with the below code. I saw this code on a udemy course done by a instructor, and he defined small partitions in a tkinter window using `.pack()` method.

The issue is that I need to use `.grid()` later down the line, and since both methods can't be used in the same program, I need to convert the `.pack()` to `.grid()`, but I have no idea how to do that. How would it be done?

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from tkinter import ttk

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Defining the window~~~~~~~~~~~~~

root=Tk()
root.title("Parent window")
root.geometry('1600x800+0+0')
root.configure(bg='#FFFFFF')
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~window~partition~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

top=Frame(root, width=1600, height=100, bg='blue', relief=SUNKEN)
top.pack(side=TOP)  #i need to change this .pack() to something else to make the program compatible with .grid() for all the lines

w1=Frame(root, width=800, height=700, bg='purple', relief=SUNKEN)
w1.pack(side=LEFT)

w2=Frame(root, width=300, height=700, bg='green', relief=SUNKEN)
w2.pack(side=RIGHT)

w3=Frame(root, width=35, height=700, bg='orange', relief=SUNKEN)
w3.pack(side=LEFT)

w4=Frame(root, width=100, height=700, bg='pink', relief=SUNKEN)
w4.pack(side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _" since both methods can't be used in the same program"_ - this is not a true statement. They can be used in the same program, they only can't both be used for widgets that have the same master.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for pointing that out, I'm sorry, I'm new to python coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use both `pack` and `grid` within the same tkinter program. Just as long as you don't mix methods that has the same parent widget.

You can see an example below with a program that mixes `pack` and `grid`:

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
from tkinter import ttk

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Defining the window~~~~~~~~~~~~~

root=Tk()
root.title("Parent window")
root.geometry('1600x800+0+0')
root.configure(bg='#FFFFFF')
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~window~partition~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

top=Frame(root, width=1600, height=100, bg='blue', relief=SUNKEN)
top.pack(side=TOP) 

# Here I create a new parent frame, to contain the widgets we wish to 
# use .grid() for instead of .pack()
gridframe = Frame(root, width=1600, height=700)
gridframe.pack(side=TOP)

w1=Frame(gridframe, width=800, height=700, bg='purple', relief=SUNKEN)
w1.grid(row=0, column=0)

w2=Frame(gridframe, width=300, height=700, bg='green', relief=SUNKEN)
w2.grid(row=0, column=1)

w3=Frame(gridframe, width=35, height=700, bg='orange', relief=SUNKEN)
w3.grid(row=0, column=2)

w4=Frame(gridframe, width=100, height=700, bg='pink', relief=SUNKEN)
w4.grid(row=0, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

To replicate the result you got with the `pack` function, please try something like the following. I am using `padx` to add the whitespace between the widgets so it matches what you saw when packing

```py
w1=Frame(gridframe, width=800, height=700, bg='purple', relief=SUNKEN)
w1.grid(row=0, column=0)

w2=Frame(gridframe, width=35, height=700, bg='orange', relief=SUNKEN)
w2.grid(row=0, column=1)

w3=Frame(gridframe, width=100, height=700, bg='pink', relief=SUNKEN)
w3.grid(row=0, column=2)

w4=Frame(gridframe, width=300, height=700, bg='green', relief=SUNKEN)
w4.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=1600-800-35-100-300)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i noticed that the windows in the original program vs yours is quite different, is there a reason why? My issue is i have already coded 250 lines after this and now that the windows are quite different, my code is invalid as everything is kinda jumbled up (putting it lightly, lol), sorry for any inconveniences.

Comment: the `pack` command will place your widgets within the parent frame according to the side you are specifying, whereas the `grid` command will place them in a grid of rows and columns. To replicate the picture you see above using grid, you would first need to reorder the columns, and then also add a column filling the whitespace, since the sum of the column width is less than the parent width

Comment: Edited my answer to show an example replicating your result

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped!