# Tkinter - After Resizing frames grid and pack methods don't work

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, grid, pack

I state that I am a Tkinter beginner and, basically, I just learnt How to resize dinamiccaly multiple frames based on the window size. Now the problem is that once I resized the frames when I try to put inside each frame created a widget, then nothing works anymore.

Below there is my code. When you run all the lines without the selected part (that I highlighted with hashtags) apparently everything work well but once the lines into the selected part are actived nothing work anymore.

In conclusion, I just would like to put inside each frame (are 3 in total) that I created many different widgets such as Labels, ComboBox, and so on. Into the top frame I would like to put widgets by using the pack method method and into the left and write frame I would like to use grid method.

If someone could help I will appreciate. Many thanks for your time...

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import os

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1366, 768  # Initial size of root window.

class InventorySystem:

    def __init__(self, root):
    
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Inventory System")
        self.root.geometry(f'{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}')
        self.width, self.height = WIDTH, HEIGHT  # Size of root window.
    
        self.create_frame()
    
    def create_frame(self):
    
        frame_width = self.width
        frame_height = self.height
    
        self.TopFrame = tk.Frame(self.root, width = frame_width, height = frame_height * 1/10, bg = "#f8f8fa", relief=tk.FLAT)
        self.TopFrame.pack(side = tk.TOP, anchor = tk.NE, expand = True)
    
        self.RightFrame = tk.Frame(self.root, width = frame_width * 8/10, height = frame_height * 9/10, bg = "#e5e6eb", relief=tk.FLAT)
        self.RightFrame.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, anchor = tk.SE, expand = True)
    
        
        self.LeftFrame = tk.Frame(self.root, width = frame_width * 2/10, height = frame_height * 9/10, bg = "#e6fce4", relief=tk.FLAT)
        self.LeftFrame.pack(side = tk.LEFT, anchor= tk.SW, expand = True)
    
        #### -> Highlighted Part Start here <- #########################################################################################
        
        #self.textbar = tk.Label(self.TopFrame, font = ('arial', 18, 'bold'), text = "Search by...", padx = 2, pady = 0, bg = "blue")
        #self.textbar.pack()
    
        #self.textbar1 = tk.Label(self.LeftFrame, font = ('arial', 18, 'bold'), text = "Search by...", padx = 2, pady = 0, bg = "blue")
        #self.textbar1.grid()
    
        #self.textbar2 = tk.Label(self.RightFrame, font = ('arial', 18, 'bold'), text = "Search by...", padx = 2, pady = 0, bg = "blue")
        #self.textbar2.grid()
   
        #### -> Highlighted Part Finish here <- ################################################################################################################
    
    def update_frame(self):
    
        frame_width = self.width
        frame_height = self.height
    
        self.TopFrame.config(width=frame_width, height=frame_height * 1/10)       
        self.RightFrame.config(width=frame_width * 8/10, height=frame_height * 9/10)        
        self.LeftFrame.config(width=frame_width * 2/10, height=frame_height * 9/10)
    
    
    def on_resize(self, event):
        """Root window size change event handler."""

        if event.widget.master is not None:  # Not the root window?
            return  # Ignore.
    
        width, height = root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height()  # Current size.
    
        if width != self.width or height != self.height:  # Updated?
            self.width, self.height = width, height  # Track change.
            self.update_frame()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    application = InventorySystem(root)
    root.bind('<Configure>', application.on_resize)  # Bind callback function to event.
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: btw you can remove all `.pack` calls in the `update_frame` method because they are useless

Comment: Here is a link that might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907815/im-having-issues-converting-python-pack-to-grid

Comment: @Matiiss Many thanks for your advice, I proved the adjustement. Could you kindly help me in solving my issue? I will appreciate it; I am working on a project and I need to figure out how to handle this problem. Many thanks.

Comment: @Derek Many thanks for your answer but I believe that I didn't make mistake by using both pack and grid within the same tkinter program. PLease if I did just do not hesitate to let me know.

Comment: I'm able to see all frames by inserting `fill = tk.BOTH` into TopFrame, RightFrame and LeftFrame. Also I replaced grid with pack (just to make sure it wasn't interfering)

Comment: Inserting `fill =tk.X` into TopFrame keeps it from filling the entire window.